# Do unused squad mates still gain levels?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm curious if I need to actively use the same squad mates for every mission to level them up, or if squad mates that don't come on missions level along side me even when unused?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. All squadmates will automatically adjust to Shepard's level, regardless of how long it's been since they've been part of the active squad.

Comment: I always found this a little easier to wrap my head around by thinking of it as "You only have one level - your party level".  Everybody levels up in sync.  (This is true in the other two games as well.)